# C# Bot connect using TcpClient class

Tags: c#, php, tcp

I'm trying to connect to a server using a IP and Port. I would like to create a `TcpClient` connection to send and receive packets later on.

I created this in PHP before using the `fsocket` functions. For example:

```
$fp = fsockopen(packets::$server, packets::$port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
fwrite($fp, packets::login('username', 'password'));
```

Well now I want to redo this using C#. I started to google about this but literally only found about a way using the `TcpClient class` So I started like the following:

```
public void tcpConnect(string ip, int port)
{
    TcpClient connection = new TcpClient();
    connection.Connect(ip, port);
}
```

I'm callingthis function in the following format:

```
functions tcp = new functions();
tcp.tcpConnect("74.113.233.195", 9061);
```

How would i continue to send packets to this tcp connection?

In PHP i used to create the packets in the following format:

```
public static function login($username, $password) {
      $packet  = "<msg t='sys'>";
      $packet .= "<body action='login' r='0'>";
      $packet .= "<login z='simpleChat'>";
      $packet .= "<nick>";
      $packet .= "<![CDATA[" . $username . "]]>";
      $packet .= "</nick>";
      $packet .= "<pword>";
      $packet .= "<![CDATA[" . $password . "]]>";
      $packet .= "</pword>";
      $packet .= "</login>";
      $packet .= "</body>";
      $packet .= "</msg>";
      $packet .= chr(0);
      return $packet;
}
```

Which I used to add to the socket in this format:

```
fwrite($fp, packets::login('username', 'password'));
```

How would i get this working using c#?

---

**Update:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace bot_console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bot started...");
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Connect("74.113.233.195", 9061);
            byte[] login = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<msg t='sys'><body action='login' r='0'><login z='simpleChat'><nick><![CDATA[turtle-1]]></nick><pword><![CDATA[password]]></pword></login></body></msg>");
            byte[] navigate = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{\"b\":{\"x\":\"cluster\",\"p\":{\"roomName\":\"|2.1.world1017.school1@|30|2|A\",\"password\":\"\"},\"c\":\"enterRoom\",\"r\":\"-1\"},\"t\":\"xt\"}");
            socket.Send(login);
            socket.Send(navigate);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

That's the actual code, sadly it doesnt seem to send the packets. Anyone an idea?

Comment: `Sockets` that's your answer. `tcpClient.Client` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So I would start creating a TcpClient client = new TcpClient(); asnd assign sockets to it?

Comment: Or you can just use a `Socket`. Like             `Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.BeginConnect(ip, port, EndConnect, socket);` where `EndConnect` is the `callback`. In the callback you can set the `Socket` to some wrapper which handles sending and receiving packets.

Comment: Thank you, i'll have a look at it :)

Comment: Updated the question, do u have any idea whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this: [Socket Send and Receive](http://www.csharp-examples.net/socket-send-receive/)

**Socket.Send method**

```
public static void Send(Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, int timeout)
{
  int startTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
  int sent = 0;  // how many bytes is already sent
  do {
    if (Environment.TickCount > startTickCount + timeout)
      throw new Exception("Timeout.");
    try {
      sent += socket.Send(buffer, offset + sent, size - sent, SocketFlags.None);
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
      if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock ||
          ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending ||
          ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
      {
        // socket buffer is probably full, wait and try again
        Thread.Sleep(30);
      }
      else
        throw ex;  // any serious error occurr
    }
  } while (sent < size);
}
```

and

**Socket.Receive method**

```
public static void Receive(Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, int timeout)
{
  int startTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
  int received = 0;  // how many bytes is already received
  do {
    if (Environment.TickCount > startTickCount + timeout)
      throw new Exception("Timeout.");
    try {
      received += socket.Receive(buffer, offset + received, size - received, SocketFlags.None);
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
      if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock ||
          ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending ||
          ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
      {
        // socket buffer is probably empty, wait and try again
        Thread.Sleep(30);
      }
      else
        throw ex;  // any serious error occurr
    }
  } while (received < size);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll have a look at this :)